# In clojure, how to write a function that applies several string replacements?

Tags: clojure

I would like to write a function `replace-several` that receives a string and a set of replacements and apply all the replacements (where the replacements see the result of the previous replacements).

I thought about the following interface:

```
(replace-several "abc" #"a" "c" 
                       #"b" "l"
                       #"c" "j"); should return "jlj"
```

Two questions:

1. Is it the most idiomatic interface in clojure?
2. How to implement this function?

Remark: To make a single replacement, there is `replace` available in [clojure.string](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.string-api.html#clojure.string/replace).

Comment: You mean `(replace-several "abc" ...`?

Comment: @Josh I don't understand your question

Comment: I'm saying that I think the "d" in `"abd"` is a typo, right? Surely it should be `"abc"`, or the `replace-several` function you're describing would be bizarre.

Comment: Thanks @Josh. You are absolutely right. Actually, I got it right in my answer :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Implementing @kotarak's advice using `replace`, `reduce` and `partition`:

```
(defn replace-several [content & replacements]
      (let [replacement-list (partition 2 replacements)]
        (reduce #(apply string/replace %1 %2) content replacement-list)))
; => (replace-several "abc" #"a" "c" #"b" "l" #"c" "j")
  "jlj"
```

Answer (score 10):

So you have `replace`, `reduce` and `partition`. From these building blocks you can build your `replace-several`.

Comment: Just noticed you can pass a `val` argument to the reduce function, if it wasn't for your comment I would never have realised!

Answer (score 6):

Here is another shot but that has **different output results**, this one uses the regex engine features so it potentially may be faster, also the interface is different, since it maps keys to replacement strings. I provide this in case it may be useful to someone with a similar question.

```
(defn replace-map
  "given an input string and a hash-map, returns a new string with all
  keys in map found in input replaced with the value of the key"
  [s m]
  (clojure.string/replace s
              (re-pattern (apply str (interpose "|" (map #(java.util.regex.Pattern/quote %) (keys m)))))
          m))
```

So usage would be like so:

```
 (replace-map "abc" {"a" "c" "b" "l" "c" "j"})
```

=> "clj"

Comment: Thank you for this code, exactly what I was looking for. Don't understand your code much yet, but I tried this: ```(replace-map "this is a test to check if it functions as expected" {"this is" "htis si" "check if" "hceck fi" "functions as expected" "whatever"})``` and it worked amazing!

Comment: In case you were wondering how it works, I'm creating a regex made of the keys of the map. `clojure.string/replace` will use that regex and pass matches to `m`, which acts as a function. Since `m` is already a mapping to what you want to replace, it will return the correct substitution.

Answer (score 6):

I'm late to this party, but for what it's worth, I think the *most* idiomatic way to do this would be to use threading and multiple replacements:

```
(require '[clojure.string :refer [replace])

(-> "abc"
    (replace #"a" "c")
    (replace #"b" "l")
    (replace #"c" "j"))

;=> "jlj"
```

The meaning of this is quite clear, though it is nice to avoid typing the "replace" multiple times.

Answer (score 6):

```
(str/escape "abc" {\a "c" \b "l" \c "j"})

; => "clj"
```

Docs [escape](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/escape)

Comment: Thanks for this nugget of gold. I had totally missed `escape`. Very nice. Will add it to the quiver.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce with replace:

```
(defn replace-several
  [str & replacements]
  (reduce (fn [s [a b]]
            (clojure.string/replace s a b))
          str
          (partition 2 replacements)))

(replace-several "abc"
                 #"a" "c"
                 #"b" "l"
                 #"c" "j")
```

Comment: It's pretty much the same as my answer. The only difference is that inside reduce, I used `apply` instead of destructuring.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I wouldn't create a separate function for this, as it is just a composition of existing Clojure functions:

`(reduce-kv clojure.string/replace "Hello" {#"[A-Z]" "J", "o" "y"}
;=> "Jelly"`

Of course if you want varargs and an interface then:

1. Yes it seems reasonably idiomatic
2. I'd implement it thus:

`(defn replace-many [string & {:as rplcmnts}]
  (reduce-kv clojure.string/replace string rplcmnts))`

Answer (score 0):

first guess..

```
(defn replace-several [string & mappings]
  (loop [grouped-mappings (partition 2 mappings) string string]
    (if (empty? grouped-mappings)
      string
      (let [[re rep] (first grouped-mappings)]
        (recur (rest grouped-mappings) (clojure.string/replace string re rep))))))
; => (replace-several "abc" #"a" "c" #"b" "l" #"c" "j")
  "jlj"
```

Comment: See my comment in reply to kotarak, I didn't realise you could pass a `val` argument to `reduce` to accumulate the result