# Making multiple string replacements using indices

Tags: string, clojure, reduce

I'm using the following cookbook recipe to substitute non-unique substrings in a text:

```
 (defn string-splice
    "cookbook recipe: http://gettingclojure.wikidot.com/cookbook:strings
     Given three arguments, string-splice will replace a portion of the old string at the       
     given offset equal to the length  of the replacement. The resulting string will be the      
     same  length as the original. The optional fourth argument 
     specifies the length of text to be replaced. If this argument length is greater than the    
     length of the new string, then the result will be shorter than the original string."

     ([target new offset] (string-splice target new offset (count new)))
     ([target new offset length]
     (str  (subs target 0 offset)   new (subs target (+ offset length))  )   ) )
```

Now suppose I have the following misspelled string

```
 (def bad-st "mary had a littl lam whose fleec was whiteas snw.")
```

and the following list of corrections with an associated index indicating where the misspelled word occurs in bad-st:

```
 (def corrections '(Mary 0 Little 11 fleck 27 white as 37 Snow 45))
```

If I want to cumulatively substitute each of these corrections into the  string while also shifting the characters in the string to accommodate a correction that is longer or shorter than the misspelled substring, I can use a version of the reduce code given for a [related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568050/in-clojure-how-to-write-a-function-that-applies-several-string-replacements).

```
 (reduce (fn [st [x y ]]
      (string-splice  st x y (count x) )) 
            bad-st
         (partition 2 corrections))
```

However, this fails to shift characters in the original text correctly. The output is

```
 "Mary had a Littlelam whose fleck was white asSnow"
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here and suggest a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem with your use of `string-splice` is that you're passing the wrong fourth argument, which needs to be the length of the replaced substring -- you're passing the length of the replacement. So you need to find the length of the bad word at the correction position.

```
(defn wsize-at 
  "size of word (non-white sequence) at position n in string s"
  [n s]
  (let [[head tail] (split-at n s)]
    (count (take-while #(not (Character/isWhitespace %)) tail))))
```

The problem this raises with using reduce is that this throws off the indexes later in the string if the replacement and replaced strings are different lengths. You can work around that by working from the end of the string backward:

```
(reduce (fn [st [s n]] (string-splice st s n (wsize-at n st)))
  bad-st 
  (reverse (partition 2 corrections)))
```

I'm not sure that `string-splice` is the right tool for this task. The corrections offsets are in the original string; a different approach would be to use those offsets to extract the unchanged segments of the original string, say with a function `good-parts` such that `(good-parts bad-st [0 11 27 37 45])` gives [" had a ", " lam whose ", " was ", " snw."] -- `wsize-at` would be part of the implementation. Then you interleave that with ["Mary", "Little", "fleck", "white as", "Snow"] and apply `str` to the result to give the desired string.

Comment: Great fix. I actually experimented with your interleave suggestion last night (before you expanded your post) but this is even better.